# SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE not Working in desktop Application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, desktop-application

i am developing desktop application in Adobe AIR, Now i am on windows, it has setting to turn off display. i set it to 1 min. it working well. but i want to turn off the display when my application is not running. i searched, and i got some result which all telling me that set `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;` in you application and  you achived what you want. all searched result say that when you set systemIdleMode to KEEP_AWAKE and display didn't off till your application is running.

i set this setting in `initialize` event of Application.

Referenace:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/SystemIdleMode.html

[image: displayOffSetting]

i think, May be some usage issue in it, nothing more in it, please help me !!!

Comment: By the way, I'm not 100% sure, so I won't include this in the answer, but I'm pretty certain you can write a C/C++ app, make an ANE (native extension), include that in your AIR app and the it will work. But you'll have to find a C/C++ programmer who could write an app that would prevent the system from going to sleep, maybe it's not even allowed by the OS, but it's outside my expertise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From adobe AS3 docs:](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html#systemIdleMode)

AIR profile support: **This feature is supported on mobile devices, but it is not supported on desktop operating systems or AIR for TV devices.** See AIR Profile Support for more information regarding API support across multiple profiles.

The important part is highlighted with bold text.

Hope it helps!